# Silverlight C# - Is it possible to add a contextual pop-down list to a textbox? (Example image attached)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, web-applications, silverlight-4.0

I'm adding a spellcheck to my application, and have added the [Vectorlight Spell Check Component](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/controls/spell_checker.aspx) to my project. When the spellcheck button is clicked I'd like to have the project make it have a pop-down wherever a spelling error occurs, and then have a pop-down list of suggestions similar to the contextual suggestions that Visual Studio gives you.

Example:

[image]

Is this doable in Silverlight 4.0 with C#? If so, what is the control called?

If not possible, then perhaps have the word get the squiggly red underline and when you right-click it then that menu has the suggestions? I've no idea how to populate the right-click menu in Silverlight either. (I would imagine I'll have to change to a RichTextBox in order to have the underline bit work - correct me if I'm wrong)

Thanks in advance for your help!

-Sootah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want it to open on right-click (as skypecakes' answer would with ContextMenu) you should just be able to use Popup.  You can position that appopriately, then have its contents be a ListBox (or ItemsControl) which has an ItemTemplate containing an Image and a TextBlock, or whatever else you like.

This is how ComboBox shows its drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

To create a context menu, use ContextMenuService.ContextMenu.

Here is a link with sample code: [New context menu functionality in Silverlight 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/15/alive-and-kickin-new-silverlight-4-toolkit-released-with-today-s-silverlight-4-rtw.aspx)